# Why would my DateFormatter .date(from: String) return nil

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Been using this function to covert a String to a Date Object.
Similar Qs on SO, however could not find one that handles my case of just the time. So this post I believe is not a duplicate.

```
    func convertTimeStringToDate() -> Date {
                //time will be "04:48"
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
                dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
                dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
                dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
                return dateFormatter.date(from: "04:48")!
            }
```

The function returns nil so crashes as its unwrapped!. I can not see what's wrong with the code.

Comment: What would be the purpose of such a function? You could create a valid date via DateComponents, in a more reliable way.

Comment: You've already specified the dateFormat as "HH:mm" which is valid for your input. Then why are you again specifying the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` which changes the format? This is why it is crashing.

Comment: That's it. I been using the function for months at was working. I guess latest beta release stopped me getting away with it. Please have that as answer and Ill accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your method should be. `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` change the format again.

```
func convertTimeStringToDate() -> Date {
    //time will be "04:48"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    return dateFormatter.date(from: "04:48")!
}
```

However, it's interesting to note that the last date format is considered valid. So, if you set the formats in reverse order, it will work!

P.S - I've only seen `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` used for output formatting.

---

**Note:** If there is a chance that you input format might change then you should safely unwrap your date and have a default date in place or something so that it doesn't crash your app.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't set dateStyle & timeStyle.

```
func convertTimeStringToDate() -> Date {
    //time will be "04:48"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    return dateFormatter.date(from: "04:48")!
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thank you for your contribution. However the question has already been answered and you point was already raised.